# Javascript: How can I define an object's properties through method calls?

Tags: javascript, function, object, undefined

I'm trying to set the 'moniker' property of my object (Robolord) through a series of function calls when the object is created. Here's my code:

```
function RobolordCreator (moniker) {
    this.moniker = moniker;
};

RobolordCreator.prototype.Attack = function (color) {
    console.log(this.moniker + " fires a " + color + " laser for " + 2 + " damage!");
};

var Robolord = new RobolordCreator(MonikerGenerator());

function MonikerGenerator () {

    function Chancey (percent) {
        function rando (percent) {
            percent = "." + percent;
            return ((Math.random() <= percent) ? true : false);
        };

        if(rando(percent) == true){
            RandomVowel();
        } else {
            RandomConsonant();
        };
    };
    Chancey(50);
};

function RandomConsonant () {
    var consonant = ["q", "w", "r", "t", "p", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m"];
    return consonant[(Math.floor(20 * Math.random()))];
};

function RandomVowel () {
    var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"];
    return vowel[(Math.floor(6 * Math.random()))];
};

Robolord.Attack("green");
```

Right now, it's printing out "undefined fires a green laser for 2 damage!" How can I make it so the RandomConsonant and RandomVowel functions pass their results when called to the 'moniker' property of my object Robolord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a couple `return`s.

```
function MonikerGenerator () {

    function Chancey (percent) {
        function rando (percent) {
            percent = "." + percent;
            return ((Math.random() <= percent) ? true : false);
        };

        if(rando(percent) == true){
            return RandomVowel(); //return Chancey result
        } else {
            return RandomConsonant(); //return Chancey result
        };
    };
    return Chancey(50); //return Moniker to caller
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UZ3JK/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a name that is multiple characters long, you'll have to store the name and add characters to it. Here is a version of the code that does that.

```
function Robolord(moniker) {
    this.moniker = moniker
}

Robolord.prototype.attack = function (color) {
    console.log(this.moniker + " fires a " + color + " laser for " + 2 + " damage!")
};

var robolord = new Robolord(generateName(8, 50))

function generateName(length, percent) {
    var name = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (randomInt(1,100) > percent) {
            name += randomVowel()
        } else {
            name += randomConsonant()
        }
    }

    return name
}

function randomConsonant () {
    var consonant = ["q", "w", "r", "t", "p", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m"]
    return consonant[(Math.floor(20 * Math.random()))]
}

function randomVowel () {
    var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"]
    return vowel[(Math.floor(6 * Math.random()))]
}

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
}

robolord.attack("green");
```

I apologize for renaming some things, I was playing with it :)

The function generateName now takes a length, and a percent of vowels (which I assumed was the original intent). This for example generates names that are 8 letters long, and 50% vowels.

I add a function called randomInt which gives you a random number within a range -- I use a function roughly like this to generate names / terrain / NPCs in games.

http://jsfiddle.net/ayvaV/

Comment: Thanks for posting that, timetocode! I am looking to make it multiple characters long, and that looks like a good way to go about it. Maybe when I'm done I'll add an edit with the expanded code.